# disjoint set and intersection of closure

Tags: general-topology

[image: Def]

I am confused about the distinction between disjoint sets and intersection of closure is empty. If A and B are disjoint, then they obviously don't intersect the closure of each other; on the other hand, if A and B don't intersect with closure of each other, then they are disjoint. So are these two statement equivalent?

Comment: II mean, do you believe that the closure *actually* exists, by which I mean that in most cases $\overline A$ properly contains $A$? If so, then by by that assumption $E\setminus A$ intersects $\overline A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If A and B are disjoint, then they obviously don't intersect the closure of each other"

This is incorrect. For example $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$, hence you can take $A$ to be the rational numbers and $B$ to be the irrational numbers and you have a counterexample for this claim.

Comment: but then wouldn't closure of A be rational numbers and closure of B be irrational numbers? Then how do they intersect?

Comment: "wouldn't closure of A be rational numbers" -- No. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. You know that closure of $A$, is a closed set, right? Well are you also aware that if $\overline{A}$ is a closed set and $(x_n)$ is such that $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \in A$ for all $n$ then also $x \in A$? Now if $A = \mathbb{Q}$ you can take any irrational number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence of rational numbers $x_n \in A$ such that $x_n \to x$, as $n \to \infty$. Thus the closure of $A$, which is the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, has to contain all real numbers. Thus $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ indeed is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I am more used to the open ball definition of closure. So is it correct to say that if I take any open ball around an irrational number, the open ball must contain some rational numbers, so all irrational numbers are in the closure of rational number?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to put it. The point is that since you can approximate any real number by rationals up to an arbitrary precision, they have to be in the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Harry. And you can approximate any real by irrationals to arbitrary precision also.